# AssistedInject and MapBinder together in Google Guice

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I have recently started using Guice and need some help.

I have a class with constructor which contains 3 different varieties on parameters to be injected. Below is the class

```
@Inject public Bullet(EntityParams entityParams, Movable movable, Renderable renderable) {
    super(entityParams, movable, renderable);
}
```

Here `entityParams` should be an assisted inject.

`Movable` interface has more than one implementation and hence needs a MapBinder to be used.

`Renderable` interface just has one implementation so its not problem.

What I have got now to do this is ->

```
public class DefaultEntityFactory implements EntityFactory {

    private final Provider<Renderable> renderableProvider;

    private final Map<String, Movable> movableMap;

    @Inject public DefaultEntityFactory(Provider<Renderable> renderableProvider, Map<String, Movable> movableMap) {
        this.renderableProvider = renderableProvider;
        this.movableMap = movableMap;
    }

    @Override
    public Bullet create(EntityParams entityParams, String movableType) {
        return new Bullet(entityParams, movableMap.get(movableType), renderableProvider.get());
    }

}
```

The factory class gives me a Bullet but I am just wondering that is their a better way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with your existing code

```
@Inject
public Bullet(
    EntityParams entityParams,
    Movable movable,
    Renderable renderable) {
    super(entityParams, movable, renderable);
}
```

First I would deal with the map binder.

```
@Inject
public Bullet(
    EntityParams entityParams,
    String movableType,
    Map<String, Provider<Movable>> movables,
    Renderable renderable) {
    super(entityParams, movables.get(movableType), renderable);
}
```

Next, I am following along with the `AssistedInject` help page.  https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/AssistedInject

First I added the `@Assisted` annotations.

```
@Inject
public Bullet(
    @Assisted EntityParams entityParams,
    @Assisted String MovableType,
    Map<String, Provider<Movable>> movables,
    Renderable renderable) {
    super(entityParams, movables.get(movableType), renderable);
}
```

And then create the factory interface.

```
public interface BulletFactory {
    public Bullet create(EntityParams entityParams, String movableType);
}
```

And bind it together.

```
bind(BulletFactory.class)
   .toProvider(FactoryProvider.newFactory(BulletFactory.class, Bullet.class));
```

You can now inject a `BulletFactory` to create new `Bullet`s.

Depending on your problem it might be better to use `@Named` instead of a multi-binder (it feels a little awkward to pass in a String type and immediately pull it out of the multi-binder) but this should work.

Comment: It's weird passing a MapBinder in Bullet but well :|